# Annotation in Atlassian Confluence

Tags: confluence

Could anyone suggest me way to make annotations in Confluence pages like Microsoft Word does? I found no such option in documentation.

Answer (score 4):

[This is now a feature of Confluence, starting in 5.7.](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/whats-new)

You can select text, add an inline comment, and also add inline comments on images or file attachments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Talk plugin](http://stiltsoft.com/talk/index.html) which allows you not only to insert annotations in any point of the page but to establish inline discussions with e-mail notifications.

Note: I am affiliated with the Talk plugin.